# How to recognize the correctness of an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, object-recognition

I'm new to image proceesing and object recognition..From a hand drawn image, how to determine the level of correctness compared to the below image using image processing. Is there any way to do this using image processing or ML? [image: clock image]

Comment: Do you have a dataset? Can these samples be artificially generated?

Comment: You could use some combination of circle and line recognition, as well as handwritten digit recognition (e.g. MNIST).

Comment: Yes I have around 70 normal hand drawn images like this. Do I need to train it? If so please tell me how to do it?

Comment: 70 is not a very big data set... but I guess you can apply "data augmentation" to a reasonable degree here (e.g. skewing, rotation, brightness/contrast, ...). I would start by picking a reasonably simple image classification model (e.g. ResNet-34). Perhaps also consider starting with pre-trained weights to "transfer learn" with.